# How can I pass data submit form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on laravel project and I try to pass color code to conroller for doing some stuff but I could not pass data of data att for a tag

I want to send it with url some thing like this :

```
http://localhost:8000/digikala/category/28?minprice=+1000+&maxprice=+100000000+&type=all&color=FFFFFF&sortBy%5Bfield%5D=created_at%7Cdesc
```

but it does not give me color and it is like this

```
http://localhost:8000/digikala/category/28?minprice=+1000+&maxprice=+100000000+&type=all&sortBy%5Bfield%5D=created_at%7Cdesc
```

here is my a tag :

```
<a class="options-color" data-color="{{ $color->code }}" style="background-color:#{{ $color->code }}">
```

here is my js :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".options-color").click(function() {
        var color = $(this).data('color');
        $('#submit').trigger('submit', color);

    });
});
```

Comment: Try using `var color = $(this).attr('data-color');`

Comment: I access to color and it's ok but I can not pass it with form

Comment: Use hidden input field and set its value using `$("#hiddField").value(color);`     Then make form submit as `$('#submit').submit();`

Comment: @Ajith you know this is a li tag inside foreach so whenever I want to send it with input type hidden it sends all foreach color at same time like this .   http://localhost:8000/digikala/category/28?minprice=+1000+&maxprice=+100000000+&type=all&color=000000&color=&color=&sortBy%5Bfield%5D=created_at%7Cdesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add color hidden input in your html:

```html
<input id='color-input' type='hidden' name='color' value=''/>
```

```js
$(".options-color").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var color = $(this).data('color');
  $("#color-input").val(color);
  $('#submit').trigger('submit');
}
```

Comment: that's it thank you I take input outside of foreach and use your js and it works well